# Load main content with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I've got a navigation bar div on all my .html page. To not copy paste the nav-bar code on every page I've created an .html page with the code and I print it on every page via jquery like this:

```
<div id="includeNavbar"></div>
```

And the code to actually print it is:

```
$(function(){
      $("#includeNavbar").load("navbar.html"); 
});
```

Is there a way to keep the nav bar loaded and load the remaining content via jquery but still using this type of printing method?

I'm using the latest Bootstrap version

Comment: Yes, what you're trying to achieve is called an SPA, single-page application if I understand right. To do that using jQuery you'd have to replace all the links on your website to events that would load the appropriate content. I can only suggest to use a more modern approach with a framework such as React.JS / AngularJS / Vue.js, ...

Comment: I actually have only two pages that can be load via the nav bar (and I'm using bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is the simple way to load a `HTML` file in other html file..
keep it up.

And also you can change your `html` file type into `php` and then you can `include` or `require` that you want place .

**Like this**

### nav-bar.php

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And your `Main.php` page that where you want another page.

### Main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php require 'nav-bar.php'?>   


</body>
</html>
```

Hope you find the answer. :)

Comment: that sounds good. So, in this way, I should be able to load via ajax the remaining part of the page, right?

Comment: Yes. The PHP `require` or `include` just replaces the `.load()` javascript for the nav bar. All else is the same. The sole difference between `.html` and `.php` is that `.php` *ALSO* will run any PHP commands that are placed between the `<?php` and `?>` tags. Otherwise, the HTML is handled identically. *Really, there is no reason to ever use `.html` -- unless your webserver doesn't do PHP (extremely rare, except on Microsoft webservers)*